# i cant see my image when i draw it in pygame, even tho its in the same folder as my python script and other python modules i need for the script

Tags: python, pygame, png, surface

[image]Im making a python program where i want to draw an image on my screen/surface with the module pygame, but when i try to draw the image, i dont see it. The image is in the same folder as my python script so that shouldn't be the problem. My syntax is also correct. So I don't know, i would appreciate if someone responds. Thanks!

```
import pygame,sys

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
second_surface=pygame.Surface([100,200])
second_surface.fill((0,0,255))

isaac=pygame.image.load('isaac.png')
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.blit(second_surface,(0,50))
    isaac.blit(isaac,(100,200))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. could you please add the output you are currently getting as well as your folder structure to help with debugging

Comment: It is a typo. `isaac.blit(isaac,(100,200))` must be `screen.blit(isaac,(100,200))`

Comment: yeah, that was actually the mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Rabbid76:

Where it says `isaac.blit(isaac,(100,200))` it should be `screen.blit(isaac,(100,200))`.

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.

Comment: Because of this, I did not answer the question.